# Is it ok to have just one big P trap at the outlet of building

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, clog, p-trap, seal

My house doesn't have P trap for kitchen sinks/bathroom sinks etc..

So instead of placing a p trap for each. May I just place one big p trap where the water is discharged from the building to outside.

FYI:

During the building construction plumber refused to add P trap fearing this could clog up the line so he didn't install

Update:

The town doesn't have underground sewer system , so I have to discharge waste water( Non-septic) in our own soak pit.

So this brings a question that do we still need a P-Trap in the first place ? because there's no external pressure to push back any gas and regarding water seal in the P-Trap,can it really stop the ingression of pests ? .. I'm not sure. So I'm wondering do we need any P-Traps except septic line.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145237/discussion-on-question-by-curiousman-is-it-ok-to-have-just-one-big-p-trap-at-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you want P-Traps at every sink. If the drain goes straight down into the floor, you want to avoid S-Traps. Instead you can install an Air Admittance Valve to avoid the drain suction issue that may pull all of the water out of an S-Trap.

Comment: If I am using P trap .. would I still need to go with Air admittance valve ?

Comment: in general, no - P-traps that connect properly / horizontally connect into the plumbing stack which does the same thing an AAV does, but better.